# Detecting elm view not working in wordpress but in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to make a number increase to a certain state when entering view. I am gonna be completely transparent with you. I have next to no website development knowledge, this is simply for a wordpress site where i couldnt find a plugin to do it for me + this gives more flexability. My knowledge simply lies elsewhere. So far i have created code that activates as soon as it enters a view, and it also counts up.

**Da Problem**

**As you can see here "https://jsfiddle.net/yd81prgq/" this works already.** I then tried putting the exact same code in wordpress on a element. Now i know that its the activatition part thats not working, since during testing i made it count up, but only as soon as the page loaded.

**Code i am putting in wordpress**

```
<h2 id="(id)">Count to ten when seen</h2>

<script>

var i = 0; 
function increment() {
    if (i<10) {
        i++;
        document.getElementById('(id)').innerHTML = i;
    }
}
function startcount() {
    setInterval('increment()', 50);
}


var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true)
        startcount();
}, { threshold: [1] });

observer.observe(document.querySelector("#(id)"));


</script>
```

*Thanks in advance :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. This puts my amount of my fault posts up to 2/2... The problem was that since the code checks when a certain element enters view wordpress is apparently build in a way that makes it happen when it exits view. Probably to do with some visuals vs. code happening in the background of wordpress. I dont know, but this was the issue. Thanks for the help recieved

**For future reference here is the working code:**

```
<h2 id="id" class="class">Make this count to ten</h2>

<script>

const sleep = (delay) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

async function counter() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    await sleep(50);
    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = i;
  }
}


var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true)
        counter();
}, { threshold: [1] });

observer.observe(document.querySelector("#id"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to remove brackets from the id. Globaly, an id should have only letters, numbers, underscore and/or dash.

PS: java is not javascript ;)

```js
var i = 0; 
function increment() {
    if (i<10) {
        i++;
        document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = i;
    }
}
function startcount() {
    setInterval('increment()', 50);
}


var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true)
        startcount();
}, { threshold: [1] });

observer.observe(document.querySelector("#id"));
```

```html
<h2 id="id">Count to ten when seen</h2>
```

An alternative with less code for the same result:

```js
const sleep = (delay) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

async function counter() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    await sleep(50);
    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = i;
  }
}

counter();
```

```html
<h2 id="id">Count to ten when seen</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks, the java/javascript was simply a typo thats my bad. Also thanks for the shortened code length, tho its not what i was looking for. I was just putting the brackets in to clarify that i meant the id to go there, i should probably have done a better job ecplaining there. In the fiddlejs link i also put the id in and it worked. My problem is that its not working with wordpress

Comment: Oh, ok sorry I misunderstood.
Can you watch your console in inscpect mode (on your browser) ? Look for any error related to you JS, edit your first post to add its, please.

Comment: I am so so so sorry for wasting your time. Turns out WordPress is just weird and didn't want to activate before you scrolled away from it. I just made it activate a bit before, so when you actually see it it starts. I appreciate the help and friendliness from you so much. Have a great say whatever you time zone is :)

Comment: Ahah no problem, it's a pleasure :)